# How to Cache database data when deploying a java web app

Tags: java, web-applications

So my question is that I want to cache some table data when I deploy my application. In this case I want to make a hash map from the data of one table when the application is deployed on the server(probably jboss or tomcat server).

I know how to use hibernate, JDBC, etc and getting the data normally is no problem, but how do I get my data retrieval code to run on its own when I'm building/deploying the application?

This is probably a pretty simple thing to do but I'm not sure how and I can't seem to find any good guide about it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a dependency injection container such as EJB, CDI or Spring? If so, which one? (Each has features that help with this)

Comment: @meriton 
I am not using any container. Of the 3 you mentioned above I'm familiar with Spring. 
Any advice on how I could achieve this with spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Of the 3 you mentioned above I'm familiar with Spring. Any advice on how I could achieve this with spring?

Spring beans default to singleton scope, and are created when the ApplicationContext is initialized (which occurs upon deployment). You can ask Spring to invoke a method when it has created a bean with `@PostConstruct` or by implementing `InitializingBean`:

```
@Component
public class CategoriesCache {
    @Inject
    CategoryRepositoy repo;

    private List<Category> cachedCategories;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        cachedCategories = repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

If you'd rather not use a dependency injection container, you can use a [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to be notified of the deployment, and perform the necessary initialization.

Comment: I would upvote you but I don't have the reputation for it :/

Thank you all the same, this worked for me.

Comment: @GameGuy1989: Even if you can not yet upvote, you can mark an answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons) to indicate it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it from a servlet build just for this purpose. Then, in your web.xml, set the servlet with a runOnStartup other then 0. This makes the webserver start up the servlet the moment the application is loaded.

Comment: I see, I'll test it out. Would this also be a good way to make my hashmap accessible across the application?

Like, If some other module needs to use the map I can call it from the servlet class?

Comment: You could simply do this by making the whole HashMap static in the servler, and then have a static method to query the HashMap.

Comment: well yes that part was obvious. I realized shortly after I wrote that comment how stupid I actually sounded but I was lazy and didnt bother to edit it :P
**meriton's** solution was the best fit though. I am now looking into using lucene for a more scalable solution for text caching searching.

Thank you very much for your help though, I appreciate it :D